# How to use NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS in place of using key and certificate files?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate

I'm new to the world of SSL/TLS but I'm getting there. While my actual use-case is different and more involved, it can be boiled down to this question; I want to set a global Certificate Authority (CA) for a big NodeJS application, which all https components will use for their communication. Of course, right now I'm dealing with self-signed certificates which are working fine if I use them like this:

```
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('local2_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('local2_cert.pem')
};

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('Yo waddup');
});

const server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

I've added the certificate to the OS trust policy (Keychain Access on Mac) and all is well. In the actual project, what I'm looking for is to provide a global CA which all components can use as a default, if they don't have a key/cert/ca set for them. Perhaps even an override behavior may be desirable but that's not required.

I understand `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is set before node runtime and changing it afterwards does nothing, so I currently manually set it before executing `node`. What I want it to look like is to remove `options` completely and for the requests to automatically detect the CA that I've set.

Again, I'm new so I'm not sure if that is a reasonable behavior to want. If there is an override behavior, I would be interested in learning that too.

Furthermore, I have a side question about SSL, is it even possible to replace this key/cert with a single `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`? Because the path I'm giving to this variable is the same absolute path that I give to `options.cert`. Is this approach wrong?

Looking forward to hearing your responses while I wrap my head around this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general you need a server cert with the server name(s) in it. Otherwise your server cannot authenticate itself. CA certs are only used to sign and therefore provide trust in those certs. Not sure entirely what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: To expand on @MaartenBodewes, CA certs are used to validate and trust _other_ systems you connect to. To act as a server (receive connections) you need a server cert (not a CA cert*) AND the matching privatekey (which is not _any_ kind of cert). * You can use a self-signed server cert which looks sort of like a CA cert but isn't used as one; in this case only client programs or systems you configure with that cert will trust your server.